Can a superhero story work in novel format?
I have an original idea for a Marvel type storyline with a few sub-plots that you would see in a typical romance/contemporary drama narrative. Would something like this work in novel form?
I can't seem to find many examples of superpowers/superheroes that haven't been written in comic book form.

For an example the webnovel 'Worm' by Wildbow, is a superhero story in a novel format

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superhero_fiction#Literature


I can't seem to find many examples of superpowers/superheroes that haven't been written in comic book form.

Searching for something like "superhero novels" turns up countless results for me. For example, a Wikipedia page of Superhero novels and lists on Reddit, Goodreads and elsewhere.
Apparently, to answer your question, "something like this" would "work in novel form".

Yes, of course it would.
My search provides some examples of long form superhero novels that even became movies; including "Soon I Will Be Invincible", "Wild Cards", "The Reckoners", and "Vicious".
Not to mention, of course, the best selling Novel series ever, "Harry Potter".
Or Stephen King's "Firestarter" or "Carrie". They may be in the Horror genre, but they are published novels and the titular heroes have some superpower.
Depending on the origin of the superhero powers, this would likely be Science Fiction or Fantasy, in either, the sub-genre would be Superhero Fiction.
Of course, the story might also fit into Action, Adventure, or even Mystery, depending on how the majority of the central plot works.
Yes, superhero stories can work as a novel, and the movie rights can be sold to directors that turn your superhero story into a movie.
